# How to copy tags input text on button click with Jquery

Tags: jquery, copy-paste

I have tags like this:

[image]

How can I implement a 'copy' function where it will copy all tags and paste them anywhere else? There will be an extra `,` in front of the sentence, for example: `HTML , Javascript , jquery , reactjs`

```js
$("#copy").click(function() {
  var content = $('.item-tag').html();
  var newdiv = $("<div>");
  newdiv.html(content);
  $('.item-tag').after(newdiv);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row p-5">
  <h4>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-tags"></i> Tags Input
  </h4>
  <div class="wrapper-tags">
    <div class="item-tag">
      <span class="tag">HTML
        <button type="reset" class="btn-close-tags">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
        </button> 
      </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="tags" class="form-control" id="tags-input" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Add Tags ...">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- copy -->
<div class="details">
  <button id="copy" data-text="Text-Copy">Copy All</button>
</div>
```

Comment: the snippet is broken anyway you can return the list of tags content as `$('.wrapper-tags .tag').each((i,tag)=>{ tagsChained.push($(tag).text().trim()); });` where `tagsChained` should be initialized as empty array

Comment: or much better without jquery: `[...document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper-tags .tag')].map( tag => tag.textContent.trim() );`